# "Private" Communication with React Flux dispatcher

Tags: reactjs, dispatcher, flux

I'm attempting to decide on the best way to handle "private" communication between a store and a react component that can exist in multiple places. I've got two instances of the same component, both of which need to communicate with the same store. But, they need to behave independently. So when one gets an error message, the other should not display it.

The issue is, because my store and my dispatcher are both singletons, both instances of the component are getting the message. Both instances are listening to the store's events, so if that's a singleton, both will receive error events.

And, both instances are using the same dispatcher, so even if I had multiple instances of the store, all of them would be getting the same message at the same time, so they would all still react to it and emit a response.

I've been looking around but I haven't seen much about handling this problem, has anyone come across anything like it? I was thinking I could pass along a reference to the caller in the action, move it through to the event response and then check it again in the component, like so:

```
// my_component.js
import dispatcher from 'dispatcher';
import myStore from 'my_store';
const myComponent = React.createClass({
    handleNewValue: function(){
        dispatcher.dispatch({actionType:'check_error', value: 'value', caller: this});
    }
    componentWillMount: function(){
        myStore.on('show_error', function(message){
            if (message.caller === this){
                doThing(message.error);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And:

```
// my_store.js
import dispatcher from 'dispatcher';
...
dispatcher.register(function(payload){
    if (actionType === 'check_error'){
       this.trigger('show_error', {error: 'is_bad', caller: payload.caller});
    }
}
```

But for complex  systems, this seems like it could get out of hand. It also seems more manual than I would like. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the issue you are having. Is it possible to have a parent component listening to the store and pass the state to its children so there is only one central component listening?